# redirecting everything to https://www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

How would I write the.htaccess file to https://www.domain.com

example

```
domain.com => https://www.domain.com
www.domain.com => https://www.domain.com
https://domain.com => https://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com => https://www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Worked, I also forgot to turn AllowOverride from NONE to ALL in my httpd.conf so all my previous attempts were not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is the code i use. I checked it at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ as well :)